# How to remove i3wm info on Desktop

Tags: manjaro, window-manager, i3, conky

I was wondering how I could remove those information I am showing you in the following images:

[image]

[image]

As I said, the window manager I am using is i3 and it has been installed through Manjaro Architect, so the config file is generated and customized by the operative system. Any hint on how I can remove this?

EDIT:

As suggested in the comments, a possible cause of this might be conky, so I am posting both the config file of i3 and conky, respectively:

- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sqnpFxxIHACf2vUz9_Y169ceZQ7Kta47/view?usp=sharing
- https://drive.google.com/file/d/18a27O8eZAtu8KkAxqUp4UkTeptsYgWav/view?usp=sharing

Comment: My guess is that your issue isn't coming from i3 but rather from the software you're using to display infos on your desktop. I think you might use conky ? If so I suggest you edit your question, tags and everything so we could provide you with a better answer.

Comment: @Martin All of this was setup by Manjaro architect, as I said in my answer. What should I modify? Regarding conky, apparently I have it up and running in the background; what does that mean?

Comment: Conky is the software used to display theses informations on your desktop. In order to improve your question, could you maybe add the contents of you config files from both i3 and conky ?
They should be located respectively in `~/i3/config` of `.config/i3/config` and for conky you can type `conky --print-config` in your terminal and paste us the result here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the config files you just posted, you could try commenting (adding `#` in front of the line) the line n°290

```
exec --no-startup-id start_conky_maia
```

I found relevant information according to your issue on this [forum post](https://classicforum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=25396.0).